# proving:Lamda is an eigenvalue of T if and only if $T-\lambda \mathrm{I}$ is not injective.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove a theorem from "linear Algebra Done right" by Sheldon Axler.

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T if and only if $T-\lambda \mathrm{I}$  is not injective. I'm a bit confused about what we assume to be true. So, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Axler's approach is non-traditional. Start by getting the definitions clear.

Answer (score 7):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then there is nonzero vector $v$ s.t. $Tv=\lambda v$.  So then $T-\lambda I$ is not injective since it sends both $0$ and $v$ to $0$.

Conversely if $T-\lambda I$ is not injective then it's kernel is not $0$ so there is a nonzero vector $v$ such that $(T -\lambda I)v=0$.  Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand some on Seth's answer, the intuition behind an eigenvalue is that it creates a linear dependence in the matrix. By definition, a linear dependence on a set of vectors implies that there are at least two linear combinations of the vectors in the set to form a given resultant. Hence, $(T - \lambda I)$ fails to be injective.

Comment: Did you mean: By definition, a linear $dependence$ on a set of vectors implies..

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks for catching that typo. :-)

Comment: No problem! I don't mean to be super meticulous, I'm just exceptionally new to linear algebra and just wanted to make sure I understood correctly.