# Prove that $T-\lambda I$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be an infinite field, $V/F$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Let $T\in \mathcal L(V,V)$. Prove that there exists $\lambda\in F$ such that $T-\lambda I$ is injective.

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/726894/469000). I am little confuse how to start it?

Comment: Do you know about determinants?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Yes, I know

Comment: In that case consider $det(T - \lambda I)$ as a function of $\lambda$. What sort of function is it and what do you know about its roots?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I didn't get could you please elaborate

Comment: its rhymes with matrimonial

Comment: its a polynomial

Comment: Yes it is a polynomial in $\lambda$. In fact, it is a nonzero polynomial. @AmanPandey do you see then what to do? Try to recall how determinants relate to injectivity.

Answer (score 0):

$T- \lambda I$ is injective iff ker$(T-\lambda I)= \{0\}$ so if there is NO vector $v \ne 0$ with $(T-\lambda I)v =0 \Leftrightarrow Tv= \lambda v$.

From the definition we know that this means: $T- \lambda I$ is injective iff $\lambda$ is no eigenvalue of $T$.

Now since $V$ is finite-dimensional we can only have finitely many eigenvalues (because each eigenvalue brings with it at least one linear independent eigenvector and eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent - therefore we can only have dim$(V)$ eigenvalues). Since $F$ is given as an infinite field we can find $\lambda \in F$ which is not an eigenvalue and that gives us that $T- \lambda I$ is injective for that $\lambda$.